# Decode audio from ArrayBuffer received over web-socket in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I am trying to send audio over web-sockets to node server where I want to store it in local file system. I am able to append the data received in a file, but it is not playable.

Most of the solution I found are for client side which use `AudioContext.decodeAudiodata()`.

**client**

```
localAudioStreamRecorder = getMediaStreamRecording(
    localAudioStream,
    'audio/webm;codecs=opus',
    (data: ArrayBuffer) => {
      handleSendRecordingChunk(socket, {
        ...getIdentityPayload({ sessionId, userId, role }),
        data,
        streamType: 'audio',
      })
    }
)
```

**server**

```
const audioStreamPass = fs.createWriteStream(audioFilePath, { flags: 'a' });
const newData = async (socket, eventData, cb) => {
  const { sessionId } = eventData.body;

  if (eventData.body.streamType === 'audio') {
    // Need help here
    audioStreamPass.write(Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(eventData.body.data)));
  }
};
```

I just want to know, how can I decode this data to something which is playable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on **server**:

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const audioStreamPass = fs.createWriteStream(audioFilePath, { flags: 'a' });
const newData = async (socket, eventData, cb) => {
  const { sessionId } = eventData.body;

  if (eventData.body.streamType === 'audio') {
    // Create the readable stream from buffer
    const readableStream = Readable.from(buffer);
    //Pipe the stream to the writeable
    readableStream.pipe(audioStreamPass)  
};
```

Comment: Same issue, data was being written to the file, but not playable.

Comment: I did that but not with websockets, but sending the stream directly to a REST API on a Nodejs be with multer as middleware, and it worked well. I think to recall that websockets need some extrastep to manage streams, socket.io had a library that helped to manage streams. When you begin sending the socket package is tyour stream complete, or you are still recording and sending chunks ?

Comment: I am sending chunks right now. I'll try sending the whole file and see if that works.

Comment: WebSocketStream API is still under development but you could give it a try https://web.dev/websocketstream/ .